# I need to display article teaser side by side in main page adaptive them

Tags: php, drupal, themes

am using drupal adaptive theme in my site and i need to display article teaser side by side in main page
i try to override node.tpl.php in my sub them with no success 
my site is 
http://www.moreburger.com/

here the image what i need 
[image]

here the image what is there

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: drupal is written in php

Comment: Ali, Maybe so, but do you actually code any PHP when using it? I don't see any code.

Comment: Actually the expected answer will override the method   adaptivetheme_process_region() this why php tag is included

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on CSS part. add `float:left` attribute to your **article** tag, it will bring all node teaser side by side and accordingly do the required css.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

In CSS add `float:left`, and to make space between the images add `margin-left:10px`